# Java - Specifically File I/O with objects

Tags: java, object, io

The exact thing I'm trying to do is to save a 2D array called num into a file called savedNumbers.data. Here is the code for saving to the .data file:

```
    private void saveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    num[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(line00Tf.getText());
    num[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(line01Tf.getText());
    num[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(line02Tf.getText());
    num[0][3] = Integer.parseInt(line03Tf.getText());
    num[0][4] = Integer.parseInt(line04Tf.getText());
    num[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(line10Tf.getText());
    num[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(line11Tf.getText());
    num[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(line12Tf.getText());
    num[1][3] = Integer.parseInt(line13Tf.getText());
    num[1][4] = Integer.parseInt(line14Tf.getText());
    num[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(line20Tf.getText());
    num[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(line21Tf.getText());
    num[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(line22Tf.getText());
    num[2][3] = Integer.parseInt(line23Tf.getText());
    num[2][4] = Integer.parseInt(line24Tf.getText());

    File outFile;
    FileOutputStream fStream;
    ObjectOutputStream oStream;

    try {
        outFile = new File("savedNumbers.data");
        fStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);

        oStream.writeObject(num[0]);
        oStream.writeObject(num[1]);
        oStream.writeObject(num[2]);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved OK");

        oStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file: " + e);
    }
}
```

That code seems to be working well.

Now I want to view all the same numbers one array at a time in JOptionPane, so three lines of saved numbers will show, then OK is pressed and another three lines of saved numbers will show until there are no more.

I am having issues with calling the numbers from savednumbers.data
Here is the code for that:

```
        //CODE FOR CALLING num FROM savedNums.data

    private void showSavedNumsBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                  

    File inFile;
    FileInputStream fStream;
    ObjectInputStream oStream;

    try{
        inFile = new File("savedNumbers.data");
        fStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        oStream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);

        ArrayList <LottoPhase1> numList;
        numList = (ArrayList<LottoPhase1>)oStream.readObject(); //THIS LINE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH

        for(LottoPhase1 ph1:numList){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Saved numbers  " +  
                "Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(ph1.getNum())
            );
        }
        oStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
    }
```

I have also tried calling the ArrayList num, numList, aList, and neither worked.
The class LottoPhase1 is created and runs with no errors, and is fully debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing Arrays to the file, not ArrayList(s).  This will not allow you to cast (ArrayList) back from the file because `ObjectOutputStream` saves the class name of the object with the object to allow it to deserialize it with `ObjectInputStream`

I would recommend either changing the data type of the object that you are writing to the file to be an ArrayList or to change the data type of the object that you are storing the data from the file in to an Array.